# How do I add Javascript handler to product options tab in admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, ce-1.9.0.1, javascript, custom-options

I need a hook to execute when "product options" tab gets loaded (I want add cursor keys movement across the grid up and down).

`window, 'load'` doesn't help because the tab gets loaded with Ajax. How do I add a better hook?

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this will help you to hook the event -

let for example we have a custom module - "customproduct"

then write below code inside etc/config.xml

```
                 <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_options>
                    <observers>
                        <custom_catalog_product_options_action>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>customproduct/observer</class>
                            <method>hookIntoCatalogProductOptionsAction</method>
                        </custom_catalog_product_options_action>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_options>
```

create an file inside Namespace/Customproduct/Model/Observer.php

```
class Namespace_CustomProduct_Model_Observer{
    public function hookIntoCatalogProductOptionsAction($observer){
        //Implement the "catalog_product_options_action" hook
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One more step for a newb - how do I add a javascript to this particular page?